# Get value of variable with the aggregated values of other variables

Tags: bash, sh

Given:

```
export A='TEST_'
export B='VAR'
```

How would I get the value of `$TEST_VAR` in this case?

Some more conditions:

> - should work both on `sh` and `bash` of the latest versions.
> - should not use any not pre-installed ubuntu dependencies.
> - should be the simplest one liner solution

Comment: There is no "latest version" of `sh`, because it's not an actual shell; it's a specification implemented by shells like `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, etc.

Comment: hey you have revised and rejected  an edit I recently made [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023455/abap-material-number-required-after-skip-first-screen/51029549#51029549) what was the reason you rejected it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indirect variable reference:

```
test_var='foo bar baz'
a='test_'
b='var'
c="${a}${b}"

echo "${c}"
test_var

echo "${!c}"
foo bar baz
```

**PS:** You should avoid all uppercase variables in Unix to avoid collision with shell internal variables.

Comment: uppercase is just for showing what I want a bit more clear :) Apparently I came to this solution. But Is there a way I can do it simplier, maybe with the one-liner?

Comment: No I don't think one liner will work here. You have to keep variable name in a separate variable first.

Comment: @Stanjer All you need is `c="${a}${b}";c=${!c}`. Is that not short enough ?

Comment: Or if you definitely know what will be in the variables you could always use eval `eval echo \$${a}${b}`

Comment: Check the solution with a sh version not linked to bash: I think the eval solution is more portable.

Comment: @WalterA: Question is tagged as `bash`

Comment: @Stanjer: Does it work for you?

Comment: @anubhava: OP also wrote "should work both on sh and bash of the latest versions", so the tag might be incorrect.

Comment: @WalterA eval has more chance of going wrong though as you can execute arbitary code, so should only be used if `!` indirection is not available.

Comment: @JID Correct, that's why you wrote `if you definitely know what will be in the variables` and I prefer the indirection when that works for the shell(s) the OP is running.

Comment: @Stanjer This is not portable. It won't work in `dash` or `zsh`, for instance, either of which could be used as `/bin/sh`.